# To show or Not to show System related error messages to the end user, which is the best practice ?

Tags: error-handling

So, When dealing with error logging and messaging, a lot of times happen that when there's an error outside of user interaction (lets say, user resources, server downtime, database connectivity, etc)

these errors have nothing to do with the user, and the user won't be able to do anything about the issue.... so

Should be the error notified to the end user? or should be only notified to the system admins ?

what are the best practices to handle this type of errors ?

Thanks

Comment: I think I answered my own question with a solid rule, but i will leave this open until the answer gets some feedback or the question gets some feedback

Answer (score 0):

One of the usability heuristics rules says:

**Help users recognize, diagnose, and recover from errors**
*Error messages should be expressed in plain language (no codes), precisely indicate the problem, and constructively suggest a solution.*

Even if it's not an user error, the user must always know what happened with his transaction